# Tracepath not working in Centos 7 with Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, centos, vagrant, traceroute

I'm attempting to use tracepath to get the traceroute for a bunch of URL's, but it's not working correctly.

For every URL I try It just returns the same result e.g

```
[vagrant@centos7 ~]$ tracepath youtube.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  centos7                                               0.094ms reached
 1:  centos7                                               0.105ms reached
 Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 1
```

I'm running Centos 7 inside a virtual box vm with Vagrant. So far I've tried running tracepath as root, I've tried removing all forwarded ports in Vagrant, and I've also tried setting up a public network in Vagrant with the examples below. None of them made any difference.

```
# config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"
# config.vm.network "public_network", ip:"10.9.170.223", :netmask => 
 "255.255.0.0", bridge: "enp65s1"
# config.vm.network "public_network",
#   use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
```

Anyone have any ideas how to get tracepath working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

`config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.0"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "/sbin/dhclient -r eth2; /sbin/route 
  del default; /sbin/dhclient eth2"`

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/2389#issuecomment-280341807